# Camera/photo gallery in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

In my application,I used PhotoLibrary,it get photo, small part of that image.In full image it picks only the corner part.i searched over the net it tells,it checks the device size and image size return device size image only.then how it is possible to bring whole image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many photos are larger than the screen size.  Corona can only show what's on screen.  You have two choices, put the larger image inside of a widget.newScrollVew() so you scroll around and see the larger image, or scale the image down until it fits on the screen.